Distributed RabbitMQ Performance Issue
I have a python application that reads data from the web and writes the retrieved text to RabbitMQ.
I have a workgroup of 6 8 core Dell Optiplex boxes running Ubuntu 22.04.
If I run 6 instances of the app on ONE box, everything runs as expected.
However - if I run on instance on each machine writing to RabbitMQ slows to a crawl (though one machine is writing faster than all the others.)
Can anyone suggest why the performance is so much worse when distributed to separate machines ?
RabbitMQ is running on it's own box.
System monitor reports CPU, RAM and Network consumptions are all under 50%
